# Create account using PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Im not to great with PHP/MySQL so excuse my ignorance.
I have a login form on my website, i have created a form for creating an account, visually everything is fine, however, i need the data to be sent to my customer account table in mysql. When i submit the form, it seems to work, creating the ID 1, but all other fields are blank.

PHP:

```
<?php

$hostname="localhost";
$username="createaccount";
$password="******";
$dbname="Island_Web_Design";
$usertable="customer_accounts";
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);

$sql="INSERT INTO customer_accounts (firstname, lastname, email, password)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
```

?>

HTML:

```
<form role="form" action="Create_Account.php">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control input-sm floatlabel createinput" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="last_name" class="form-control input-sm createinput" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm createinput" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm createinput" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-sm createinput" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account" class="btn btn-primary btn-block register">
                        </form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data that gets printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: If you are new! learn using mysqli or PDO!!!!

Comment: I get that you are not happy with my code, i picked it up off the net, if you would kindly advise (in full) how i should go about it. this was my question. Thanks

Comment: The default method for forms is GET, not POST. All of your variables would be available in the `$_GET` array. As for coding something better there are tons of links in the comments which will help you.

Comment: as far as i know im using MySQLi its with godaddy cpanel

Comment: You're using the `mysql_*` functions, not `mysqli_*`

Comment: Well today it wasnt working, and i called godaddy and they switched the Mysqli function on, so im assuming that im using that? also, this is the code i got from godaddy.... as far as i would assume, they are correct.

Comment: To fix your code add `method="post"` to your form tag as @Jeeves said below. GoDaddy enabled MySQLi for you, but you actually have to use the MySQLi functions in order to invoke it.

Comment: Thanks @jay, where can i find these functions? how come it still works without?

Comment: MySQLi functions are prefixed with `mysqli_`. You can find more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: The reason that it still works is because GoDaddy has not upgraded PHP to the point where deprecation of the functions are met. When they do, if you're not using MySQLi or PDO, all of your database interactions will fail.

Comment: @jay, i did notice when looking around there is a "version" drop down, i didnt want to touch it though incase i broke it.

Comment: I feel your pain @JoeyG

Comment: so from my code above, what could i implement to make it safer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you should stop using `mysql_*` functions for new code. It is removed from the language in the latest version (7). Instead upgrade to either `mysqli` or `PDO`:

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Secondly you should prevent the SQL injection holes you have in your code:

[How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Thirdly you should hash your password to prevent them from leaking when you have for example a security hole in your application.

[`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Finally to get to your question: if you don't tell your form to `POST` it will make a `GET` request instead. Change your form to `<form role="form" action="Create_Account.php" method="post">`.

You can and should debug your code yourself for issues like these. The simplest form would be to use [`var_dump();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on your variables to see whether the contain what you think they contain. And you can also inspect the requests being made by opening the developer tools of your favorite browser.

Your code could / should be rewritten as:

```
<?php

$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=Island_Web_Design;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'createaccount', '******');

$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO customer_accounts (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password');

try {
    $stmt->execute([
        'firstname'=> $_POST[firstname],
        'lastname' => $_POST[lastname],
        'email' => $_POST[email],
        'password' => password_hash($_POST[password], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 14]),
    ]);
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

echo "1 record added";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ideally id like to see visually. can someone put something together so that i can understand the difference?

Comment: Yeah. OP chould be able to read the entire answer, because everything on top is actually more important. Also you are overwriting my changes.

Comment: @JoeyG I tried to add an image, but as a new user I am not allowed to add more links.

Comment: where do i put this passowrd_hash segment? @jeeves

Comment: Let me write up an example.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the information and suggestions in my post. To verify the password supplied by the user later on log in see http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php for more information.

Comment: @jeeves, i get a server error. im assuming its because of the PDO bit?

Comment: Check your error log. Also what PHP version are you on?

Comment: PHP version 5.4 but will only let me go to 5.5. PDO is ticked but there is lots of variations that are not ticked.

Answer (score -3):

Please never do this:

```
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]')
```

read this: [Is SQL Injection possible with POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087182/is-sql-injection-possible-with-post)

Fix add method="post" inside form balise, thanks @jay

Comment: This has been covered in comments and is not an answer to the question.

Comment: i just start on stackoverflow i can't do comment

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: @jay ok, so show me an example of what you would do in this case, with my coding above? that would help alot. thanks

Comment: @jay this is why i just put link...

Comment: Link only answers are considered *bad*, especially when they do not actually answer the question.

Comment: I am reading your links, like i stated at beginning, i have limited knowledge, so everything im reading is foreign to me. I guess i will search and find somehow. thanks anyway.

Comment: To fix your code add `method="post"` to your form tag @JoeyG as Jeeves said above.

Comment: Thank you @jay, this works now. I will take a look at the links you posted to get a better understanding, but for now this is working.

Comment: And to be perfectly clear @JoeyG, I apologize if you were under the impression I was belittling anyone. It is always my goal to be positive and to teach. Comments may seem terse and straightforward, but they are meant to do only one thing....teach. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You may not get that on SO every time @JoeyG. This is more like a "teach a man to fish" kind of place and rarely will you get a truckload of code written for a problem.